# "Compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope" for a Worksheet Change event

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I currently have the following code that allows me to insert columns on sheets that I specify based on a certain value:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const SOMESHEETS As String = "*MemberInfo-20*C-Proposal-20*Schedule J-20*NOL-20*Schedule R-20*NOL-P-20*SchA-3-20*Schedule H-20*NOL-PA-20*Schedule A-20*Schedule A-5-20*C-Proposal-19*MemberInfo-19*Schedule J-19*NOL-19*NOL-P-19*NOL-PA-19*Schedule R-19*Schedule A-3-19*Schedule A-19*Schedule H-19*"      
                                                                                                                                             
    Dim KeyCells As Range, ColNum As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set KeyCells = Range("B30")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) Then
            ColNum = KeyCells.Value
            If ColNum > 0 Then
                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then 'Skip this Sheet and process next sheet
                    If CBool(InStr(LCase(SOMESHEETS), LCase("*" & ws.Name & "*"))) Then
                            InsertColumnsOnSheet argSheet:=ws, argColNum:=ColNum
                    End If
                    End If
                Next ws
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue I am having is that every sheet listed with a -19 needs to be linked to KeyCells range of B30, which is listed.  Every sheet with a -20 needs to have a KeyCells Range of B36.

The following code provides a compile error.  I understand why its throwing out this error, but can't figure out a way around it

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Const SOMESHEETS As String = "*C-Proposal-19*MemberInfo-19*Schedule J-19*NOL-19*NOL-P-19*NOL-PA-19*Schedule R-19*Schedule A-3-19*Schedule A-19*Schedule H-19*"      ' <<< change / append sheet names to suit
                                                                                                                                         '     be sure each sheet name is between * characters
Dim KeyCells As Range, ColNum As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set KeyCells = Range("B30")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) Then
        ColNum = KeyCells.Value
        If ColNum > 0 Then
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then 'Skip this Sheet and process next sheet
                If CBool(InStr(LCase(SOMESHEETS), LCase("*" & ws.Name & "*"))) Then
                        InsertColumnsOnSheet argSheet:=ws, argColNum:=ColNum
                End If
                End If
            Next ws
        End If
    End If
End If

Const SOMESHEETS As String = "*MemberInfo-20*C-Proposal-20*Schedule J-20*NOL-20*Schedule R-20*NOL-P-20*SchA-3-20*Schedule H-20*NOL-PA-20*Schedule A-20*Schedule A-5-20*"      ' <<< change / append sheet names to suit
                                                                                                                                         '     be sure each sheet name is between * characters
Set KeyCells = Range("B36")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) Then
        ColNum = KeyCells.Value
        If ColNum > 0 Then
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then 'Skip this Sheet and process next sheet
                If CBool(InStr(LCase(SOMESHEETS), LCase("*" & ws.Name & "*"))) Then
                        InsertColumnsOnSheet argSheet:=ws, argColNum:=ColNum
                End If
                End If
            Next ws
        End If
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Youre defining `SOMESHEETS` twice

Comment: I understand that SOMESHEETS is defined twice.  I wasn't sure if I would be able to break out the sheets to have two different keyCell values be applied.

Comment: You can, but you'll need to use `din somesheets as string` and then set somesheets inside the `if`

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off refactoring to remove the repetition:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ProcessChange Target, Range("B30"), _
          "*C-Proposal-19*MemberInfo-19*Schedule J-19*NOL-19*NOL-P-19*NOL-PA-19*Schedule R-19*Schedule A-3-19*Schedule A-19*Schedule H-19*"
          
    ProcessChange Target, Range("B36"), _
          "*MemberInfo-20*C-Proposal-20*Schedule J-20*NOL-20*Schedule R-20*NOL-P-20*SchA-3-20*Schedule H-20*NOL-PA-20*Schedule A-20*Schedule A-5-20*"

End Sub

Sub ProcessChange(Target As Range, KeyCells As Range, SheetsList As String)
    Dim ColNum As Long, v, ws As Worksheet
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        v = KeyCells.Value
        If IsNumeric(v) Then
            ColNum = v
            If ColNum > 0 Then
                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then 'Skip this Sheet and process next sheet
                        If CBool(InStr(LCase(SheetsList), LCase("*" & ws.Name & "*"))) Then
                            InsertColumnsOnSheet argSheet:=ws, argColNum:=ColNum
                        End If
                    End If
                Next ws
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```